# Youtube API upload returns status=400&erro=FAILED in nexturl

Tags: youtube-api

My API interface for uploading a video to Youtube through a browser successfully goes through all OAUTH2 authentication and returns the URL and TOKEN for the form to post a video to Youtube. When the uploading appears to finish, it redirects to my "nexturl" page with a URI similar to:

http://mynexturl.com?status=400&error=FAILED

And there is no video on Youtube.

This is happening when logged into different Google accounts, on different browsers. My code used to work and then it started occassionally getting this error and now it always gets this error.

The only forum reference to this problem that I can find is unanswered. Would REALLY appreciate any ideas.

FYI, I am not using a framework. All code home-grown.

Here is the basic form that gets generated. I believe URL encoding is all okay.

```
<form name="vidform"
action="https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/action/FormDataUpload/AIwbFAT3znCsDfC_Be
5RiqMy2L4xpBqTsxrRbG5Q7iiKJweoXHl3b6UyVM9fLJTNTuKAptTiQY0hrVzYArABtKOGgCAxNYHa8BbsjQrWokwSp51HUckPI56amf4xeaMask7G9B5Gttsh
?nexturl=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fcs%2Fbuild%2Fquilt%2Fyoutube_fin%2Ehtm
%3Ffinish%3DY%26state%3D2220" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
onsubmit="return chkYouFile(this);">
<input name="file" type="file">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="AIwbFARRkinNm2Hey6JBCgxIO3mReNLQDoxLAoDBK_jq6FT1-epwRt2tfRECeONF9QQRHcLJsxKAzbHIQEvNJC-c1P1aqoFvK1jTkl4U94vMgdHGrkDuSAfKws1IU-GpkvNeMYVoI223lL3r0FP28KU4xef3K6Hmg6TJjyf9u4HxoIW7FHqQybZuGRpR3mdfkVfl0pObgfX9uj2J1m2DwPnWU0kOBw0Q4hezzczitsEi1b_cE-E7o0miJP2xTLB-kZTv6aPSvTtbgr7w-57Q09igVcOrhsrmu9tfhnHWTi6peXdvu5BeRnoWAXhz_ZKeH_Q0FN2-SzW0">
<input id="UpNow" type="submit" value="Upload Now!" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:11pt;">
</form>
```

It is returning properly to the nexturl page.

Comment: Can you post a link to your code so that we can help diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the nexturl parameter is not URL encoded,
the nexturl parameter's value should be URL encoded

Comment: I added the form code to my problem. I do believe all is encoded properly. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

At some point as I was tearing my hair out, I added an & (ampersand) to the end of the **nexturl** URL. That is, the nexturl field/value went from:

```
nexturl=http://mydomain.com/youtube_fin.htm?finish=Y&state=2220
```

to:

```
nexturl=http://mydomain.com/youtube_fin.htm?finish=Y&state=2220&
```

(I purposefully am showing the non-url-encoded version above for clarity)

The upload immediately started working. No more error=FAILED messages. Interestingly, I removed the & to see if it would start failing again, and it did NOT. So I am still most puzzled over this, but it is working for now, so I am happy.